# How to check hidden files in IntelliJ

Tags: java, shell, intellij-idea, command-line, intellij-plugin

In Normal Command prompt, for "ls -a", we will get all the files and Hidden files as well. But in IntelliJ Command prompt, how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "IntelliJ command prompt"?

Comment: I mean in the intelliJ Terminal

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA terminal should work the same as your "normal command prompt".

Comment: What happens when you enter `ls -a` into the IntelliJ terminal?

Comment: @KiranKutte, the _Terminal_ window is _alt + f12_.

Comment: ls -a
Get-ChildItem : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'a' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Attributes -Directory -File -Hidden -ReadOnly -System.
At line:1 char:4
+ ls -a
+    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: this error i am gettting when i run ls-a

Comment: You are running a PowerShell prompt inside the Terminal window. PowerShell does not recognise `ls -a` because that's a Unix command. How are you managing to get `ls -a` to work from the command prompt? You must be running some other shell from the command prompt, such as Mingw/Git Bash. Run that shell from the IntelliJ terminal window too.